# How to dynamically adding value to the object using loop

Tags: javascript

How to dynamically adding value to the object using loop.

```
var object = [
    {lat: 1, lng: 2},
    {lat: 3, lng: 4},
    {lat: 5, lng: 6},
];
```

Comment: Adding what and where?

Comment: Adding new value to the object. Result var object = [
        {lat: 1, lng: 2},
        {lat: 3, lng: 4},
        {lat: 5, lng: 6},  {lat: 7, lng: 8},
    ];`

Comment: First you do not have an object, you have an array that contains objects.

Comment: Read up on the `Array.prototype.forEach` method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
object.push({lat:4,lng:7});
}
```

is this what you mean?

```js
var object = [
    {lat: 1, lng: 2},
    {lat: 3, lng: 4},
    {lat: 5, lng: 6},
];
document.write("<br/>Object before:"+JSON.stringify(object));

for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
object.push({lat:4,lng:7});
}

document.write("<br/><br/>Object after:"+JSON.stringify(object));
```

Comment: I need not apply bracket ?

Comment: It is correct? 

 var object;

    for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
        object.push[{lat:4,lng:7}];
    }

Comment: your example contains the variable "object" which is an array of objects. The array has a method push() which allows you to add other objects at the end of the array. The correct way to call it is as I already pointed out object.push(...) not object.push[...]